# how can I set download size unlimited in apache 2.4.9 on wampserver

Tags: apache, codeigniter, wampserver

in my web application which is CodeIgniter, users can download a lot o file. but there is a problem when download more than 25 MB.

how can I set download size unlimited in apache 2.4.9 on wampserver ?

Comment: It would help if you told us what problem. Show us the error from the php error log or the codeigniter error log.

Comment: Are you downloading more than one file at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Try these different settings in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini

Although it is safer to use the wampmanager menus like this

```
(leftclick)wampmanager->PHP->php.ini
```

Find:

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 8M
```

Change to:

```
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```

Then restart wamp to take effect

Comment: Also if you are going to move this to a hosted server eventually make sure that the host allows you to make similiar changes to `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`